# Check A Picturebox For A Specific Image Name

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource, picturebox

I need to check a picturebox for a specific image. I know you can check if the picturebox is populated with an image...

```
If Not pictureBox.Image is Nothing Then

Else

End If
```

But in my case, I need to check this picturebox for an image I loaded earlier on in the process.

Here is the current code I'm using to load the image...

```
PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.TestImage1
```

I thought by using the following code I could check the image name, but this apparently does not work.

```
If PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.TestImage1 Then
  'do something
Else
  'do something else
End if
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image does not have any knowledge of the file name or any other name that it has been loaded from. What you can do, however, is compare images pixel-by-pixel. Try this code:

```
Public Function AreSameImage(ByVal I1 As Image, ByVal I2 As Image) As Boolean
  Dim BM1 As Bitmap = I1
  Dim BM2 As Bitmap = I2
  For X = 0 To BM1.Width - 1
    For y = 0 To BM2.Height - 1
      If BM1.GetPixel(X, y) <> BM2.GetPixel(X, y) Then
        Return False
      End If
    Next
  Next
  Return True
End Function
```

Credit goes [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/d80970b9-303a-4bf6-8b7f-7bdde93a2c00).

A useful article I found when looking for this answer:

- [Compare two images to find differences greater than a threshold value in VB .NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_image_compare_threshold.html)

This is how you can check if your images are less than 100% equal, i.e. similar.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim a as image=my.resources.image1.jpg' imported file from resources
Dim b as image=my.resources.image2.jpg' imported file from resources

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

picturebox1.image=a
picturebox2.image=b

end sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   if picturebox1.image is a and picturebox2.image=b then

      picturebox2.image=a
      picturebox1.image=nothing
   else
      picturebox2.image=b
      picturebox1.image=a
end if
end sub
```

..................Just try it! :)